# React Contenteditable Not Focusing with Ref

Tags: reactjs, focus, contenteditable, ref

Feel like I'm going crazy -- can't seem to get past this. Upon inputting any text, we immediately lose focus. Calling focus() on the ref appears to have absolutely no effect.

**UpdatePage.js**

```
export default class UpdatePage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const that = this;

    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      db.collection('users/' + user.uid + '/updates')
      .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
        const updates = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          const updateData = doc.data();
          updates.push({...updateData, doc_id: doc.id});
        });
        that.setState({
          updates: updates,
        });
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const todaysDate = new Date();

    return (
      <div>
        <UpdateDeck date={todaysDate} {...this.state}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Update Deck**

```
export default class UpdateDeck extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div key={this.props.date}>
      <UpdateCard key={"A"} {...this.props}/>
      <UpdateCard key={"B"} {...this.props}/>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

**UpdateCard.js**

```
export default class UpdateCard extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Card>
        <ListGroup>
          {this.props.updates
            .map((update, i) => {
              return <Update key={'Update_' + update.doc_id}
                             update={update}
                             {...this.props}/>;
            })}
        </ListGroup>
      </Card>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

**Update.js:**

```
export default class Update extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  updateCard(doc_id, text) {
    const ref = this.myRef.current;
    db.collection(...).doc(doc_id).update(...)
      .then(function () {
        ref.focus();
      })
  }

  render() {
    return <ContentEditable
        key={this.props.update.doc_id}
        html={this.props.update.text}
        innerRef={this.myRef}
        disabled={false}
        onChange={e => this.updateCard(this.props.update.doc_id, e.target.value)}
      />
  }

}
```

Needless to say, the `db.update()` function updates `this.props.update.text`, but I'm wondering if this is the source of my issue since I'm not using state.

Using this ContentEditable npm library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable

Comment: Can you shopw the code for ContentEditable or is it from some library

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri this is the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable

Comment: In any way is the update component remounting on change. You can check it by logging in componentDidMount function

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes, you're right it's re-mounting. Even when I add a key to ContentEditable, it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: in that case can you share the parent component too?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri sure, just added.

Comment: Is `update.doc_id` changing?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri no, it's not. Those ID's are coming straight from the DB, and I'm currently testing just editing a single update. So none of the IDs changing upon re-rendering. Validated that the keys aren't changing using React chrome extension.

Comment: Its just a wild guess and not a solution but could you try `key={index}` instead of  `key={'Update_' + update.doc_id}` .Also you need not provide key for `<UpdateCard key={"A"} {...this.props}/>`

Comment: Actually no, not the above comment. Just remove `key={this.props.date}` from `<div key={this.props.date}>`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri WOW! Great catch! Face palm that I didn't catch that. I spent about 4 hours trying to debug this. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your focus is lost is because the component is getting remounted instead of re-rendered.

Now one reason this things happens is because you add a key prop to the component that changes between re-renders. When this happens React things that the component has changed and remounts it.

Now you add a key `key={this.props.date}` on the div and I assume on each change on contentEditable date prop might ahve changed causing each and every child of it to remount

You also do not need a key prop unless you are returning elements from a loop

you could simply write your code like

```
export default class UpdateDeck extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <UpdateCard {...this.props}/>
      <UpdateCard {...this.props}/>
    </div>;
  }
}
```